# iOS React Native: only "Bundle React Native code and images” when there are RN changes

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

“Bundle React Native code and images” build phase takes place every time when editing unrelated project files in Xcode.

What way can you configure this build phase to only take place when rebundling the RN code and images would be required?